# How can we type a variable which is a method in TypeScript ? (Using Chart.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I got the following interface:

```
export interface LineChartProps {
     ...
    yAxesTicksMin?: number,
    yAxesTicksMax?: number,
    yAxesTicksCallback?: (value: number | string, index: number, values: number[] | string[]) => string | number | null | undefined
}
```

Then in the ChartJS object to "populate" my chart component I got the variable `yAxesTicksCallback` assigned to substitute the callback:

```
...
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min: yAxesTicksMin as number,
    max: yAxesTicksMax as number,
    stepSize: 1,
    callback: yAxesTicksCallback as (value: number | string, index: number, values: number[] | string[]) => string | number | null | undefined,
},
...
```

Here is where the problem begins. When I define the "variable as type" it throws the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, If I remove this line, the program compiles.

What am I doing wrong? The `callback` has that same type in the original interface (ChartJs interface).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In you type definition you declare that `yAxesTicksCallback` is optional by adding the identifier `?`. Consequently TypeScript will compile this as `() => ... | undefined` the latter which causes the error when you're typecasting it to the function type. There's a bunch of ways to resolve this and it's a bit hard to advise on the best one without further context–but the first thing I'd investigate is if it's possible to remove the `?` from the interface, this would allow you to remove the typecasting as well. I think this is nice because usually when I implement a typecast, I later find out that I was just being lazy and could structure my code in a better way.